# ASP.NET Core 2.x Session IdleTimeout not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, session-cookies

Application built with ASP.NET Core 2.x using cookie authentication and hosted in IIS.

I'm trying to set cookie expiry to 120 minutes and idle timeout to 30 minutes.
ie. while user is navigating pages and submitting forms, if the user leaves the page/form for 30 minutes and tries to interact with the page or form again, that requires validation(requires login) and should be taken back to the options.LoginPath value.

I've tried setting the idle-timeout to a low value of 10 seconds and reviewed several other stackoverflow, .Net and Microsoft articles looking for a suitable solution for this.

Would absolutely appreciate any suggestions or other things I could try to achieve the idletimeout.

ConfigureServices method:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddCookie(options =>
                {
                    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = false;
                    options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
                    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);
                    options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/Error");
                    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // -> This decides which page to send users to 
                    //When cookie expires the user will be returned to the login page
                }
            );
            //services.AddMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```

Configure method includes:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseSession();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
```

EDIT 27/04:

1. Went into IIS and the Application Pool > Advanced Settings > Updated Idle Time-out (minutes) to 30 and set Ping Enabled to False
2. Opened the site and navigated to a page only an authorised person can access and left it for 45 minutes, then tried to submit a HttpPost using Form submission on the page and I expected the session to have expired (I have a SessionExpired and Error[catch unhandled] page) though it successfully submitted the post.
3. Have also checked that the 120 minute cookie expiry works, confirmed that it takes me to the SessionExpired page as expected

Any suggestions what else I could try in IIS?

Comment: Are you trying to change the idle-timeout in code level? Have you tried modifying the idle-timeout in IIS?

Comment: Trying to change it at code level as we're yet to confirm if we will be keeping it in IIS or moving to something like Azure.

Comment: How about this, Using Web.config
<system.web> <sessionState timeout="20" />
<system.web>

Comment: As this is a .NET Core app it doesn't have a web.config until publish and that just refers to the .net core settings. I do have a session timeout as per the options.Cookie.Expiration code line; just that the options.IdleTimeout line in the AddSessionOptions isn't acting as I would expect

Comment: What I think is that your IIS settings is overriding the code change?

Comment: Ah, so you're suggesting IIS is overwriting the code. Any suggestions where I could look in IIS??